# Is this possible using only angular-formly?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, angular-formly

So, I have this form, made using AngularJS [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/AEKyv60FZpNVnirNirFw?p=preview), which basically lets me create a purchase object to send to a server, i.e, it lets me select a store where I bought some items, set a "date of purchase" (just a text field for now), and add those items to the object I'm gonna send.

After the submit button it is shown how the model I'm going to send will look like, showing the id of the store, the "datetime", and an array of items.

My question is: Is there a way of doing this form using angular-formly only?

The question arises because I've been reading formly's docs and I haven't figured out how to make it create such a dynamic model as this form does, i.e., with a variable-length array of items of the purchase, or if it is at all possible.

Thanks in advance for any clue you can give me to answer this question :)

The code for the form is as follows:

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module('test', []);
})();
```

The html page:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css"/>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.js"></script>
      <script src="inab.js"></script>
      <script src="PurchaseCtrl.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body ng-app="test">
      <div ng-controller="PurchaseCtrl" class="col-md-4">
            <h2>Purchase</h2>
            <div class="panel panel-default">

              <div class="panel-heading">Title</div>

              <div class="panel-body">

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Store</label>
                  <select class="form-control" ng-model="model.store">

                    <option ng-repeat="store in stores" value="{{store.id}}">{{store.name}}</option>
                  </select>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>date-time</label>
                  <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="model.datetime"/>
                </div>

                <div ng-repeat="item in items">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                      <label>{{item.label}}</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                      <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="item.nome" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-alert submit-button col-md-2" ng-click="removeItem()">remove item</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <button ng-click="addItem()">Add item</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submit-button" ng-click="onSubmit()">Submit</button>
            <pre>{{model | json}}</pre>
          </div>
    </body>

  </html>
```

The controller:

```
(function(){
  angular.module('test').controller('PurchaseCtrl', ['$scope', function(scope){

    scope.stores = [{id: 1, name:'Store 1'}, {id: 2, name: 'Store 2'}];

    scope.items = [];

    scope.datetime = '';

    scope.store = '';

    var i = 0;

    scope.model = {
      store: scope.store,
      datetime: scope.datetime,
      items: scope.items
    };

    scope.addItem = function(){
      scope.items.push({label: 'algo' + (i++), nome:''});
    }

    scope.removeItem = function(){
      scope.items.splice(scope.items.length - 1);
    }

    scope.onSubmit = function(){
      console.log(scope.model);
    }
  }]);
})();
```

Comment: Yes it is possible.I've created something similar.You need to have a look at repeating sections in Angular Formly.[Link](http://angular-formly.com/#/example/advanced/repeating-section)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Satej commented, it was with repeated sections. Thanks :)